# Gunicorn supervisor service is automatically getting restarted nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I am getting trouble for keeping service constantly running.

my job_name.conf

```
[group:job_name]
programs=gunicorn_job_name

[program:gunicorn_job_name]
command=/var/www/job_name/bin/gunicorn_django -c gunicorn.conf.py -p gunicorn.pid
directory=/var/www/job_name/project
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
environment=LANG="en_US.UTF-8",LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8",LC_LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

when I try:

```
supervisorctl pid all
    2651
    1613

supervisorctl pid all
    2678
    1613

supervisorctl pid all
    2716
    1613
```

Here what I am noticing is that the first process pid is changing on every hit.
According to my knowledge `pid` only gets change when reloading the `supervisorctl`

```
supervisorctl status
job_name:gunicorn_job_name RUNNING    pid 2847, uptime 0:00:03
gunicorn_ckiller_api RUNNING    pid 1613, uptime 0:19:52

supervisorctl status
job_name:gunicorn_job_name STARTING   
gunicorn_ckiller_api             RUNNING    pid 1613, uptime 0:19:55
```

I don't know why "job_name" process is restarting automatically.
And this is happening without reloading the `supervisorctl`.

Comment: That was a crash buddy. Check your error logs you'll find the culprit. .. well, first ADD error logs then look at them :P -- ps, this has nothing to do with `fabric` remove it

Comment: Which logs? I am checking nginx logs. But i am not getting any useful information over there.

Comment: If there is error then check the log using command: tail -f <process_name> stderr